# Getting the index of listbox of New Created Item

Tags: c#

I've written my code in C# as a Windows Form using VS2013

Basically I'm Creating a new User which calls the CreatingData();

Then i am calling three Query Methods to refresh the Listbox where all the data is populated.

After i call these Methods i need to have the new user Selected so certain fields get populated correctly and i can continue on with adding permissions to the user with the other methods i've already created.

**MY Questions: How do I or What code is needed that will Select the New created user in the list box so that text boxes and labels get updated properly?**

```
    private void bntSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CreatingData();
        QueriesUser();
        QueriesUserRole();
        QueriesProfile();
        ///SELECT CREATED USER IN LIST BOX HERE SO THAT lblUserId.Text is the Correct ID BEFORE calling other Methods!
        //lstEditUser.SetSelected(????); OR ?? < --- This is what i need but dont know how to write it.
        if (rdbYes.Checked == true)
        {                
            AssignPackageLicense();
        }
        QueryAssignPackageLicenses();
        QueryAssignAssignments();
        QueryAssignQueues();

    }
```

Comment: Like: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.setselected%28v=vs.110%29.aspx ?

Comment: WPF? Silverlight? WinForms? ASP.NET?

Comment: @DanielC This might work. i need to try it lol

Comment: @dymanoid it's a winform

Comment: Please post your relevant code. Are you following a pattern like MVP, MVC, or MVVM?